# How to use APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class frm_main
    Private Const APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE As Integer = &H180000
    Private Const WM_APPCOMMAND As Integer = &H319

    Declare Function SendMessageW Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr

    Private Sub btn_mute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_mute.Click
        SendMessageW(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Me.Handle, CType(APPCOMMAND_MICROPHONE_VOLUME_MUTE, IntPtr))
    End Sub
End Class
```

It doesn't work, but I can mute the speaker.

Comment: What doesn't work? This will toggle the microphone input on/off. Were you expecting something else?

Comment: Btw, possibly, use the more recent version of the declaration:     `<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> Friend Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, wMsg As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr End Function`. Spans 3 lines.